# How to write Java Azure Function which write to Azure SQL?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to write Function, which get triggered by Service Bus and write code to Azure.
I'm here stuck not able to access DB at all. 
I don't get any error here, but neither I get Print results from select statement(Test2).

What is wrong in code?

Before running this code, I have downloaded jdbc driver and followed following example.
http://biercoff.com/add-microsoft-sql-jdbc-driver-to-maven/

```
package com.function;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

/**
 * Azure Functions with Azure Storage Queue trigger.
 */
public class TopicTriggerSQLOutput {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the specified path. The 
message contents are provided as input to this function.
     */
   @FunctionName("TopicTriggerSQLOutput")
    public void run(
         @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
            name = "message",
            topicName = "newtopic",
            subscriptionName = "newsubscription",
            connection = "topicconnstring"
        ) String message,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        /*Creating SQL Connection. I need help here:
        */


            String connectionUrl = 
"jdbc:sqlserver://sql...;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";

            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {

                    context.getLogger().info("Test 1"); // This is printed out.

                // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
                String selectSql = "SELECT TOP 10 artist FROM [dbo].[RadioEventsTarget]";
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

                // Print results from select statement
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3));
                    context.getLogger().info("Test 2"); // This is never printed.

                }
        }
            // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        context.getLogger().info("Message: " + message); // this is printed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the sql part by using your code, the code works fine.

[image]

As you didn't got any error, the only reason that I can think of is that there is no data in the table(**RadioEventsTarget**).